# When we use size() function inside a loop condition, does it calculate the size for every iteration?

Tags: c++, loops

For example, `for(int i=1;i<=arr.size();i++)`

PS : arr is user defined vector

In the above example, does the `arr.size()` executes for every iteration or it calculates the size once and stores it somewhere for future iterations.

If the size() gets executed for every iteration then what will be its time complexity?

Comment: The time complexity of the `size` function is usually O(1). Most likely the container have a "size" member, so all it does it fetching its value. Which the compiler can inline. Unless you have measured, benchmarked and profiled to know this is a top-three bottleneck, then there's really no need to worry.

Comment: What worries *me* is that you start a loop using some kind of array or other container using the value `1`. Remember that array and vector indexes are *zero* based. And unless you really need to use indexes for some reason, you should really be using a [range `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

Comment: By `arr` do you mean something of type `std::array`? (in which case the size is a compile time constant and compilers know that)

Comment: No it will not : https://godbolt.org/z/Ws5b5ET9d. The compiler will deduce the size of the array is 4 (it is a constant/invariant).  Line 22 of assembly.  Never underestimate what compilers can do for you (pulling out invariants from loops is one of them).

Comment: Watch this [What has my compiler done for me lately](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bSkpMdDe4g4). In general don't prematurely optimize, write readable code and if you think you have performance issues, then profile your code to find the actual bottleneck (and this is often not directly what you think it is)

Comment: It depends on many things.  What is `arr`?   If `arr` is a standard container (you haven't said) does the loop body change the number of elements in `arr`?   Does the loop body introduce undefined behaviour (e.g. by accessing `arr[i]` when `i == arr.size()`)?  Have you built with or without optimisation (if `arr.size()` doesn't change, and there is no undefined behaviour)?

Comment: What container you are using? Is it a std::vector or std::array? The answer to your question will be dependent on that.

Comment: [Here's another example](https://godbolt.org/z/x43YEP7vE), supposing your array is really a vector. As you can see, the size may not be recalculated, as long as the compiler can figure out that it isn't necessary. Compilers will have to err on the side of caution though, and such analysis is necessarily imperfect.

Comment: Side note, with std::array/std::vector you probably won't need `.size()` at all. Use [range based for loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) whenever you can

Comment: For a current compiler, `.size()` is required to be constant time-complexity for all standard containers. For C++98/03, it wasn't strictly required, but strongly suggested for most containers, most of the time. The one that might not have been was `std::list`. For `std::list`, you have a choice: you can have constant time for either `.splice()`, or `.size()`--but if one always gives constant complexity, there are a few cases the other requires linear complexity. But as of C++11, `.size()` is always O(1), and `.splice()` is O(N) when necessary to allow that.

Comment: "PS : arr is user defined vector" <- This tells us precisely nothing about how `size` is implemented for this data type.

Answer (score 3):

It may depend on optimization levels, but in general yes. It is called every time through the loop. If you think about it the loop could possibly be modifying the array so `size()` is not guaranteed to be const.

Comment: If `arr` is `std::array`, then size will not change. If it's a `std::vector` then this can change between loop iterations.  Further clarity is needed from the OP to offer a good answer.

Comment: If `size()` is constant, at lower level optimizations, the program will waste time performing a branch and return.  Branches are subject to branch prediction as to whether to reload the instruction cache or not.  By placing the value of `size()` into a variable, the compiler can replace the branch with a register or variable access.